# Create Mysql view from two table not working

Tags: mysql, view, case

I have two table

**ORDER**

```
prod_id   qty   gst    gst_rate
1         25    yes    18
1         25    no     0
2         10    yes    12
3         5     no     0
```

**RETURN**

```
prod_id    add    less   gst_rate
1          5      0      0
1          10     0      18
3          0      2      0
```

About the table `ORDER`

> Product 1 have order 25 with gst 18% and order 25 without gst. Product
>   2 have order 10 with gst 12%. Product 3 have order 5 without gst.

About the table `Return`

> Product 1 without gst have extra qty 5. Product 1 with gst have extra
>   qty 10. Product 3 (no gst) have less qty 2. Product 2 have no extra or
>   less qty.

So I have to create a **VIEW** for each entry in `ORDER` table

Result should look like this

```
prod_id    qty   gst_rate   add   less
1          25    18         10    0
1          25    0          5     0
2          10    12         0     0
3          5     0          0     2
```

What I tried is:

```
SELECT ord.prod_id, ord.qty, ord.gst_rate, ret.add, ret.less FROM order ord LEFT JOIN (SELECT case when ord.gst='no' then (select sum(add) from return,order where order.prod_id=return.prod_id and return.gst_rate=0) else (select sum(add) from return,order where order.prod_id=return.prod_id and return.gst_rate!=0) end as add FROM return) as ret ON ret.prod_id=ord.prod_id
```

But it is not working..

Comment: Views don't allow sub queries

Comment: The follow up to the above comment is that if you can refactor your query so that it has no subqueries, you should be able to create a view from it.

Answer (score 0):

you query could be refactored  avoiding  subquery  ..

```
SELECT ord.prod_id, ord.qty, ord.gst_rate, 
     case when rd.gst='no' then t1.sum_add else t2.sum_add end as add 
FROM order ord 
LEFT JOIN (
  select prod_id, sum(add) as sum_add
  from return 
  INNER JOIN order ON  order.prod_id=return.prod_id and return.gst_rate=0
  GROUP BY prod_id
) t1 on t1.prod_id = ord.prod_id
LEFT JOIN (
  select prod_id, sum(add)  as sum_add
  from return 
  INNER JOIN order ON  order.prod_id=return.prod_id and return.gst_rate!=0
  GROUP BY prod_id
) t2 on t2.prod_id = ord.prod_id
```

(the less was not in you code so i have omitted  by select )

Comment: `Unknown column 't1.add' in 'field list' `